# Name of the distribution $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$?

Tags: probability-distributions

We are given a random variable $X$ with PDF:
\begin{align*}
f(x ; p) &= p^x(1-p)^{1-x} \ , \\
\end{align*}
where $0 \leq p \leq 1$ is the parameter and the support is $x \in \{0,1\}$.

Anyone knows what the name of this distribution is? And if so, could you please help me understand how I can infer to that? I only know of simple distributions such as uniform, gaussian...etc.

---

**Update!**

Thanks [Minus One-Twelfth](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/643882/minus-one-twelfth)! I appreciate the quick answer, but I was hoping for some more elaboration on how I can infer to the distribution type.

Comment: Note that $f(0;\,p)=1-p,\,f(1;\,p)=p$.

Comment: "how I can infer to the distribution type" You either know the name or you don't. Regardless, knowing the name won't help you use it. The actual distribution (which you have a nice formula for there) is what lets you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). Not sure what you mean by "infer to that".